# Is there any decent way to embed microsoft OneNote into my web app? ( React js )

Tags: reactjs, rich-text-editor, onenote, rte, onenote-api

In short, I'm building  web application with **React** which will need to support Microsoft **OneNote**. But as far as I've searched, there is no embeding for OneNote?

So my question is. How to implement **as much functionality as possible using OneNote Graph Api and React**? What I thought so far is using react-rte... but that package supports only one editing box ( one note page consists of multiple editable parts which each has it's own position, cordinates, etc..  so thats doesn't seem to be a solution..) Maybe i missed any other good libraries or there aren't any?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Embedding OneNote in your web application is currently not supported.

If you believe we should have this functionality, I encourage you to upvote this item in uservoice: https://onenote.uservoice.com/forums/245490-onenote-developer-apis/suggestions/5909975-allow-live-onenote-pages-to-be-embedded-on-a-websi